# React JS-passing child component value to parent component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-component, react-context

I am a total beginner at this.

I have a window that is rendered that has a SASHeaderTemplate at the top as a page header and in that template I want to pass in a value for the Title. That alone would be easy with props.

But - the value of the title should be set by the child component .. in my screen shot below...if SASAppDispatcher gets to display then it should pass "Hello World" to the title.
I haven't provided values for the other child components but in the end each child component would have its own custom title.

I have looked at CreateContext and Redux and I'm not sure if there are other methods. In my mind I am trying to avoid re-doing the content of SASHeaderTemplate in each child component. So I thought I could create SASHeaderTemplate once and simply pass in a value.

I think I am suffering from info overload and now paralysis. SASHeaderTemplate will be called multiple times from my app in many different files at many different places in the node tree.

Would anyone care to give me the baby step approach to this please? I am not against reading but I have reached that paralysis frustrated stage.

[image]

The SASHeaderTemplate would render something like this (above) where the h3 would reflect that passed value - in this case I was attempting {this.props.headerTitle} just as a placeholder...

As I don't know where the node tree this will be called from I thought it needs to be this "global" variable that any child component can update. I know I'm sorta understanding it. But I need something to take {title} in the child and make it {headerTitle} in the SASHeaderTemplate.Anything I seem to attempt seems to be more complicated than I think it should be.
:-)

[image]

Comment: You might want to look into the context API or similar libraries, such as react-redux or react-mobx.

Comment: You can have a context provider wrapping the dispatcher, and within the dispatcher consume the context with some setter and change the title. Aside from this please: 1. Don't post code images, share minimal code [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 2. Make a minimal example in codesandbox, by this time someone would fix your example and you would get an answer.